# add task to running loop and run until complete

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a function called from an `async` function without `await`, and my function needs to call `async` functions.  I can do this with `asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(sleep())` but the `run_until_complete` at the top level doesn't run until the new task is complete.

How do I get the event loop to run until the new task is complete?

I can't make my function `async` because it's not called with `await`.

I can't change `future` or `sleep`.  I'm only in control of `in_control`.

```
import asyncio


def in_control(sleep):
    """
    How do I get this to run until complete?
    """
    return asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(sleep())


async def future():
    async def sleep():
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print('ok')

    in_control(sleep)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(future())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the package [`nest_asyncio`](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio) will help you out here. I've also included in the example fetching the return value of the task.

```py
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio


def in_control(sleep):
    print("In control")
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(sleep())
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
    print(task.result())
    return


async def future():
    async def sleep():
        for timer in range(10):
            print(timer)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Sleep finished")
        return "Sleep return"

    in_control(sleep)
    print("Out of control")


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(future())
```

Result:

```
In control
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Sleep finished
Sleep return
Out of control
[Finished in 10.2s]
```

Comment: i don't have control of `future`.  i'll update the question to clarify

Comment: If the parent `async` function is being called with `run_until_complete`, there's probably not much you can do to prevent the main loop terminating. Otherwise if you can expect the main loop to last long enough on its own, you could try adding a callback to the task for `sleep()` if you need to do more work after `sleep()` completes. But that isn't reliable given you don't have control over how long the event loop runs for.

Comment: yeah the caller is just running `in_control()` a bunch of times and then terminating.  i can launch a thread that does `time.sleep()` the first time `in_control()` is called, but i guess if i'm going to launch a new thread, i might as well make another event loop

Comment: @Jayen I've updated the answer after some more digging - see if it works for you now.

Comment: nest_asyncio works!  now to figure out how to let `future` call `in_control` multiple times